# Do the following concepts belong to syntax or semantics?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, semantics, syntax, types-and-programming-languages

I am not very sure about the difference between syntax and semantics.

Does each of the following concepts belong to syntax or semantics?

- terms
- values:   terms that are possible ﬁnal results of evaluation.
- types
- (typing) context
- evaluation (rules)
- typing (relation)?

Here are two examples from *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce.

For example, I thought evaluation (rules) belongs to operational semantics, so values should also belong to operational semantics, by the definition of values. Why does the book list "values" under "Syntax"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures of formulas, please.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to reproduce the two figures, and I think It is better to have them than not at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a good idea to try to divide everything in PL into "syntax" and "semantics". Often we mix things. Nevertheless, as for your question, we normally divide things up like this:

- terms, values and types are syntactic entities, as each of them is described by grammatical rules, so these are syntax
- a typing context is syntax in simple cases, when we can describe contexts using grammatical rules
- the typing relation is considered to be part of *static semantics*, i.e., the typing relation is determined by the structure of the terms (as opposed to their operational behavior),
- the evaluation relation is part of *dynamic semantics*, i.e., the evaluation rules explain the operational (dynamic) behavior of terms.

You did not mention *denotational semantics*, which gives *mathematical* meaning to terms and types. It is considered to be a separate thing of its own.

Comment: Thanks. (1) values are special terms which are the final results of evaluating other terms. Which term is a vealue depends on evaluation rules, so I guess value belongs to semantics, just as evaluation rule does. Or am I wrong? (2) How do you "describe typing contexts using grammatical rules"? Typing context seem to be used together with typing relation, so I guess typing context belongs to semantics, just as typing relation does. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Re (1): No. Values are defined *separately* from evaluation rules using grammatical rules. It is a *theorem* that evaluation always terminates in a value. Such a theorem guarantees that your computations never get "stuck" at terms that are not values.

Comment: Re (2): for simple type theory a context is just a list of types, or possibly a list of pairs `x : A` where `x` is a variable. This can be desribed by a grammar easily enough. For complicated theories (say, dependent type theory), contexts are complicated and one needs to make a judgement form for "is a well-formed context". But you are not asking about such complicated cases.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "It is a theorem that evaluation always terminates in a value." In the untyped lambda calculus, evaluation of term `(lambda x. x x) (lambda x. x x)` doesn't terminate in a value, see p65 of the book. Does the book mention something like "Values are defined separately from evaluation rules using grammatical rules"? From p34 of the book, I saw that values are defined as special terms which are the final results of evaluating other terms, so I think it  implies that which term is a "value" is derived from evaluation rules.

Comment: There are several possible notions of value: head-normal, weak head-normal, normal form. These are all syntactic, as they say things like "there is no subexpression of the form $(\lambda x . M) N$". So this is still a syntactic criterion.

Comment: Even if in some text you saw someone defined values as "final results of evaluation", I am telling you that (a) it's better to avoid this and define values separately (for several reasons that we cannot go into here), and (b) in most cases values are defined by a syntactic criterion so that they are recognizable by inspection.

Comment: Thanks. Does the concept of normal form belong to semantics or syntax? Note that a value is a term in normal form, while a term in normal form isn't necessarily a value. For example, in the untyped arithmetic expressions, `pred true` is in normal form but not a value.

Comment: Normal form is the property of a syntactic term that refers to its syntactic structure, therefore it's a syntactic concept. But what do you expect to gain by dividing everything regarding $\lambda$-calculus into syntax and semantics?

Comment: Well, your example of `pred true` just shows that there is an important distinction between values and normal forms, and that one should not conflate the two.

Comment: To OP. I am working through the book and implementing it in Prolog. The values are not needed for `operational semantics` as you call them or for evaluation. The one usage where they are absolutely essential is for checking the evaluation results. If the final evaluation does not end with a value then there is a bug in the code. continued.

Comment: Where this really hit home was when doing pure untyped Lambda-calculus. Many other sources use Church encodings mixed with delta-reductions or other means of reduction and so one can get evaluation results that are not abstractions. But since only abstractions are the final allowed value for an evaluation of pure untyped Lambda-calculus I went back and looked for the reason why, both in reading TAPL and other sources. In doing such learned a lot more about Lambda-calculus that is easily not grasped with casual reading.  Continued.

Comment: So no, values are not operational and not used for evaluation, they are essential for verification of the evaluation result when writing in a programming language or before programming languages in verifying ones hand calculated result.

Comment: Since I have not finished the book one question I ask along the way is, are the leaves of an AST always a value?

Comment: @AndrejBauer The answer is OK (so no upvote for now) but I found more value in the comments. This really needs an updated and expanded answer for others that read this. Maybe then I can give it an upvote. :)